# Do I need visa to recheck bags at Riyadh?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, transit-visas, riyadh

I am a Pakistani student with a valid UK residence permit and Netherlands permit. I am transiting through Riyadh airport and have to transfer my bags myself. My layover is 8 hours and I have the confirmed ticket for my onward flight to Amsterdam. Do I need a visa for reclaiming my bags and re-checking them?

Comment: You have two separate tickets, right?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105145/transfer-from-turkish-to-air-india-in-riyadh-king-khalid-airport

Answer (score 6):

> Do I need a visa for reclaiming my bags

No

> and re-checking them?

Most likely yes. This sounds very much like two separate tickets. In this case the airline for your first flight will have to verify that you have all required documents to enter Saudi Arabia. The fact that you have a second ticket leaving the same day, makes no difference to them: They sold you a ticket to Saudi Arabia and what you do there and how long you are staying is no concern of them. Without proper entry documentation, they will not let you board in the first place.

There are exceptions to this rule, but they are quite rare.

Things are different if you are on a single ticket, however in this case there should be no need for you to transfer the bags yourself.

Comment: No visa for reclaiming the bag, but yes for rechecking them? I think there might be a typo?